# Cannot connect to GitHub - Issue in download a Go function - Connection timed out

Tags: git, go, github, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am facing an issue while running a Go command for cloning

```
go get -u --tags nopkcs11 github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim

# cd .; git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
Cloning into '/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim: exit status 128
```

I am using an AWS virtual machine and I have checked all my inbound traffic. I searched other questions of this website for the same issue but it didn't help. Request you guys to help on this.

Comment: This is unrelated to the `go` command; the command that's failing is `git clone` for the stated reason. You need to figure out why you can't connect to `github.com:443`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by updating inbound and outbound details and selecting the ip address for all SSH,TCP etc as -'from anywhere'